# Problem uploading a image with formData and fetch in Vue

Tags: vue.js, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

im geting a error 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to upload a image with a API.

This is the code I use:

```
fnguardar(event) {
      const fileN = event.target.files[0];
      const formdata = new FormData();

      formdata.append("imagen", fileN, "img1.jpg");

      console.log("guardando");

      fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + this.url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formdata,
        headers: {
          Accept: "multipart/form-data",
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .then((i) => {
          this.i = i;
          console.log("datos enviados");
          console.log(i);
        });
    }
```

The input code:

```
<input type="file" id="img" name="img" @change="fnguardar($event)" />
```

What I´m missing?

Comment: You should inspect the browser's DevTools (the Network tab) and see what exactly is being sent to your server. Perhaps there is nothing wrong on the client-side - but maybe there is a bug on your server-side code ?

Comment: If I use the form method it works correctly. Its something with the code I think, but dont know what could be.

Comment: If you request crash the server, the error must be on the server side, otherwise your error should be handled properly.